# use textbox in column header - c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, columnheader

I have a textbox and a button in my columnheader. The textbox should be collapsed until i press the button. 
The problem is i can't access the textbox programmaticly.

I tried `tbTest.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;` but it shows the following error:

"The name 'tbTest' does not exist in the current context"

I also need `tbTest.Text` and it doesnt work.

---

Here's my code:

```
<DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                            <ContentPresenter />


                                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Padding="5 0" Content="Gruppe" VerticalAlignment="Center" Cursor="Hand" Foreground="White"/>

                                            <TextBox x:Name="tbTest" Grid.Column="1" Width="150"  Visibility="Collapsed" TextChanged="tbTest_TextChanged"></TextBox>

                                            <Button Grid.Column="2" x:Name="btnFilterGroup" Style="{StaticResource MyButton}" Width="16" Height="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0 0 10 0" Click="btnFilterGroup_Click">
                                                <Button.Background>
                                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources/filter.png"/>
                                                </Button.Background>
                                            </Button>


                                            <Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="2" BorderThickness="0.6" 
                                                   BorderBrush="{Binding VerticalGridLinesBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Cursor="SizeWE"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the textbox which is used inside the datagrid using it's name.
You have to use the following code to access the textbox on button click.

```
<DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="28,152,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="132" Width="436">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                            <ContentPresenter />


                                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Padding="5 0" Content="Gruppe" VerticalAlignment="Center" Cursor="Hand" Foreground="White"/>

                                            <TextBox x:Name="tbTest" Grid.Column="1" Width="150"  Visibility="Hidden" TextChanged="tbTest_TextChanged" Loaded="tbTest_Loaded"></TextBox>

                                            <Button Grid.Column="2" x:Name="btnFilterGroup" Width="16" Height="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0 0 10 0" Click="btnFilterGroup_Click">

                                            </Button>


                                            <Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="2" BorderThickness="0.6" 
                                                   BorderBrush="{Binding VerticalGridLinesBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Cursor="SizeWE"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Active"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Now, add the following code to the loaded event of the textbox to get the instance of it.

```
private void tbTest_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            tblBox = (sender as TextBox);
        }
```

Finally, add the following code to the button click event to change the visibility of the textbox.

```
private void btnFilterGroup_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            tblBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
```

Hope this helps your need.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of two things, if you want to access the visibility in your view model, create a visibility property then bind to it from your xaml. Alternatively you can access the text box's visibility in the code behind (xaml.cs) where tbTest.Visibility would work.

This I believe to be the standard practice and would work identically for accessing the text on the textbox as well - Create a string property on the view model and bind using similar code to below.

`Text="{Binding txtBox1String, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`

Comment: do i have to do this for each columnheader?

Comment: Well that is up to you, if you want access to the information entered in the column header I would say yes, if not then you don't have to, alternatively if you only want the information for (lets say) a button click event then there is no need to bind to properties on the view model as all the information is accessible from the xaml.cs where the event would  trigger.

Comment: what do you mean with xaml.cs. where do i find it?

Comment: It is generally automatically created when adding new wpf items - https://gyazo.com/4432221890273f672d82d47b52f44f39 if this has not been automatically added for yourself you can create one simply by creating a new class item with the same name (but include .xaml.cs) and make it a partial class of your view.

Comment: In your view you would also have to add something like this at the top x:Class="Views.AdminView"