# User input to change column header text in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am creating a DataGrid by importing an excel file. I want users manually to be able to change column names from the application.

Edit: Workaround at the bottom

My desktop app will have below logic:

1. Load excel file and display table in DataGrid
2. Manually change Column names to match fixed text. (e.x. Column "PricesZZZ" renamed to "Prices", "LeadTimeXXX to "LeadTime")
3. Export DataGrid to new excel template with only relevant columns that are matched by fixed text (thus the need to have correct
   names).

Excel file can have multiple columns and only several of those columns have relevant information and the only way to identify them is to match header name or some other way have user "tell" program which column holds which information.

I need to find a way to change Column name based on user input as I think it's most straightforward. I'm new to c# so sorry if my thinking is a little backwards.

Below is the code snippet I have so far. Might not be relevant for this specific problem, but may help visualize. I use EPPlus library

**Import excel**

```
private void btnOpenXL_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Create OpenFileDialog 
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();



    // Set filter for file extension and default file extension 
    dlg.DefaultExt = ".xls";
    dlg.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xlsx;*.xls;*.xlsm;*.csv";


    // Display OpenFileDialog by calling ShowDialog method 
    Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();


    // Get the selected file name 
    if (result == true)
    {
        // Open document 
        string filename = dlg.FileName;

        //call another class to draw the table
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = GetDataTableFromExcel(filename).DefaultView;
        MessageBox.Show("import done");
    }
}

public static DataTable GetDataTableFromExcel(string path, bool hasHeader = true)
{
    using (var pck = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage())
    {
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
        {
            pck.Load(stream);
        }
        var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
        DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
        foreach (var firstRowCell in ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, ws.Dimension.End.Column])
        {
            tbl.Columns.Add(hasHeader ? firstRowCell.Text : string.Format("Column {0}", firstRowCell.Start.Column));
        }
        var startRow = hasHeader ? 2 : 1;
        for (int rowNum = startRow; rowNum <= ws.Dimension.End.Row; rowNum++)
        {
            var wsRow = ws.Cells[rowNum, 1, rowNum, ws.Dimension.End.Column];
            DataRow row = tbl.Rows.Add();
            foreach (var cell in wsRow)
            {
                row[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Text;
            }
        }
        return tbl;
    }
}
```

**Export excel**

```
private void btnExportToXL_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    dataTable = ((DataView)dataGrid.ItemsSource).ToTable();
    ExportDataTableToExcel(dataTable);
    MessageBox.Show("export done");
}

public void ExportDataTableToExcel(DataTable dataTable)
{
    string path = "C:\\test";
    var newFile = new FileInfo(path + "\\" +
                                DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".xlsx");
    using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
    {
        ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
        ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dataTable, true);
        pck.Save();
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(newFile.ToString());
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Workaround by double clicking on any cell in datagrid:

```
private void dataGrid_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGrid.SelectedIndex == -1) //if column selected, cant use .CurrentColumn property
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please double click on a row");
    }
    else
        {
        DataGridColumn columnHeader = dataGrid.CurrentColumn;
        if (columnHeader != null)
        {
            string input = Interaction.InputBox("Title", "Prompt", "Default", 0, 0);
            columnHeader.Header = input;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the column names of the datagridview. But note, that this change is limited only to the grid and not it's data source. So in a nutshell, for simple representational purposes, you can use the following code:

```
dataGrid.Columns[i].HeaderText = "New Column Name"; //i is the index of the column
```

You can call this code form a Button click event of a Text change event of the input where the user provides the header name. Additionally, if you have the column names beforehand, you can replace then column headers with new values right after the data source has been bound to the grid. Change the headers after this line:

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = GetDataTableFromExcel(filename).DefaultView;
//Set new column names here
```

Comment: thanks. I managed to ducktape solution with input box and changing datagrid column names. Do you know how I can do the same to ItemsSource?

Comment: Sorry I was too quick to post. I made cosmetic change by clicking and changing `DataGridColumnHeader.Content = input` [ref post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895803/how-do-i-capture-click-events-on-a-datagrid-column-headers). However, when I iterate through columns `foreach (DataGridColumn column in dataGrid.Columns)` It still shows old name.  I can use your approach to change header text `column.Header = "New Header"`, but not sure how to initiate this event from XAML when clicking on a specific column. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33363181/use-textbox-in-column-header-c-sharp-wpf

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Link was not much help, but I found workaround by double clicking any cell in column to get the column position with `dataGrid.CurrentColumn` and initiate column headr change with `dataGrid.CurrentColumn.Header = input`. I still would prefer clicking column directly, but if I do, it does not have `CurrentColumn` property. More information in post EDIT.